# NestJS Routes not Found even though they have been mapped

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nestjs, backend

I am having trouble connecting to my locally set backend when I try to reach it from my React app. Routes are getting mapped and I can even use them when I made API calls from Insomnia but when I try to do it from React, I get a 404 error

Here is the code and the error messages:

```
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  @Post('register')
  register(@Body() dto: RegisterDto) {
    return this.authService.register(dto);
  }

  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
  @Post('login')
  login(@Body() dto: LoginDto) {
    return this.authService.login(dto);
  }
}
```

[image: Failed request]

[image: Mapped routes]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was cors error and I solved it by adding app.enableCors(); to main file